# Ubuntu 18.04.1 issue with 26" Screen

Tags: drivers, display, screen, intel

[In the image can observe the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiY2G.jpg)

I have an PC All-in-one AIO Lanix 26"

Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E7500 @ 2.93GHz × 2 
Intel® G45/G43
Gnome 3.28.2
64 bits

I cant see all view zone of the screen only 20" of 26" available, I try change the resolution but do not change anything.

I hope anybody can help me.

Thks a lot...!